# Pass value from the visualforce page to a global variable of a class

Tags: apex, controller-extension, apex-param, visual

I tried to pass the input field variable value(as provided by the user) to a global variable in the controller. I have the following code.

```
<div class="Modal">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="DateTimeofComment">
        <apex:outputLabel>Comment Sent Date</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputfield id="CommentDate" value="{!AModel.dateTimeInput}" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!AModel.save}" value="Save" id="saveCommentButton" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**AModel** is an extension class. In the **AModel** class I have the global variable

```
public DateTime dateTimeInput {get;set;}
public void save() {
    //Save Code.............
}
```

What is happening is that whenever I am trying to save the visualforce page code given above it is throwing the following error.

**Error:**

> Could not resolve the entity from `<apex:inputField>` value binding `{!AModel.dateTimeInput}`.  can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Can anyone tell me how this issue will be ressolved?

Comment: Whatever you given in the InputField must goto the Controller. Is that what you are asking? Then you should use the Apex:Param to pass the value from VFPage to Controller. You may look this link...https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good solution to this is to use a proxy object in the controller to capture the dateTime value

```
public Event evt { // proxy object, fld StartDateTime is creatable
  get {
    if (this.evt == null)
         this.evt = new Event();
    return this.evt; 
  set;
}
```

... elsewhere in your controller (like in the custom `save` action method, you can use `this.evt.startDateTime` to reference the user-entered datetime.

Then your VF page is:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="DateTimeofComment">
        <apex:outputLabel>Comment Sent Date</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputfield id="CommentDate" value="{!evt.startDateTime}" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="saveCommentButton" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The advantage of this approach is you leverage the builtin SFDC datetime picker and you can avoid all the hassle of parsing datetimes.

Comment: Now that is something amazing.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are getting describe this:

If it's not an sObject field, you have to use one of the typed input tags. In your case, you would use `<apex:inputText>`.

Additional options include `<apex:inputcheckbox>` and `<apex:inputTextArea>` to handle other data types.

Comment: I am appending the date picker to it. If I use <apex:inputText> it would not be a input date field. Is there any other way? @Mr.Frodo

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this, check this: [Datepicker in Visualforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097bvIAA)

Comment: One more nice [post](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/11/date-picker-in-visualforce-page.html) on this.